# How to optimize MySQL query for matching multiple comma-separated values in a single column?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, query-optimization

I am working with a MySQL database and I have a column (let's call it status_column) which contains comma-separated values. The possible values in this column are 'NA', 'NON_NA', 'PSG_REQUIRED', or any combination of these, such as 'NA,PSG_REQUIRED' or 'PSG_REQUIRED,NON_NA', etc.

I need to write efficient queries to retrieve rows based on the following conditions:

- Rows where status_column contains 'NA' but not 'NON_NA'.
- Rows where status_column contains 'NON_NA'.
- Rows where status_column contains both 'NA' and 'NON_NA'.

It's important to note that I want to exclude any rows where status_column may be NULL or an empty string, even when I'm looking for both 'NA' and 'NON_NA'.

I've tried using the FIND_IN_SET() function in MySQL, which requires me to use two separate conditions for the third case (matching both 'NA' and 'NON_NA'). Here are my current queries:

For condition 1:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0;
```

For condition 2:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) > 0;
```

For condition 3:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0
AND FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) > 0;
```

These queries work, but I am wondering if there is a more optimized way to achieve the same results, especially for the third condition where I am currently using two FIND_IN_SET() calls.

I also considered using the REGEXP function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE status_column REGEXP '(^|,)NA(,|$)|(,|^)NON_NA(,|$)';
```

However, I'm unsure if this is the most efficient approach or if there are any better alternatives that I might be missing.

Could someone suggest a more optimal query or confirm if the REGEXP approach is the best way to handle this in MySQL?

Comment: If it is MySQL v8+, you may use `'(?<![^,])N(?:ON_N)?A(?![^,])'`. Using the lookarounds with double negagtion + re-factoring the pattern to match in a linear way (that is, with no possibility to re-try the formerly consumed text) will be good enough.

Comment: The `most efficient approach` is to fix the table design

Comment: *I have a column (let's call it status_column) which contains comma-separated values.* Does the data normalization is possible? if true then do this. If not then there is no a chance for optimization, you'll have full table scan anycase.

Comment: `(?<![^,])N(?:ON_N)?A(?![^,])` finds either `NA` or `NON_NA` and if you need both, you will need something like `^(?=.*?(?<![^,])N(?:ON_N)?A(?![^,])).*` which is already not quite "optimal". Think of the DB re-factoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index on expression.
This expression can produce bit mask for values 'NA','NON_NA','PSG_REQUIRED'
Search (WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0) condition my convert to `IN(....)`.

If you carefully write out the expressions when creating the index and search conditions, the query will use the `Index range scan`.

This method is possible when the set of search phrases is fully defined (consists of a limited set of values).

See example

Test data

```
create table test (id int,status_column varchar(100));
insert into test values
 (1,'NA,NON_NA,PSG_REQUIRED') -- 7
,(2,'NA,PSG_REQUIRED')        -- 5  
,(3,'NON_NA,PSG_REQUIRED')    -- 6
,(4,'PSG_REQUIRED')           -- 4
,(5,'NA')                     -- 1
,(6,'NON_NA')                 -- 2
,(7,'NON_NA,NA')              -- 3
;
create index ix_keys on test
  ((case when FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
   +case when FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) > 0 then 2 else 0 end
   +case when FIND_IN_SET('PSG_REQUIRED', status_column) > 0 then 4 else 0 end
  )
  );
```

Query

```
select * 
  ,(case when FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
   +case when FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) > 0 then 2 else 0 end
   +case when FIND_IN_SET('PSG_REQUIRED', status_column) > 0 then 4 else 0 end
  ) fv
from test
where (case when FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
   +case when FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) > 0 then 2 else 0 end
   +case when FIND_IN_SET('PSG_REQUIRED', status_column) > 0 then 4 else 0 end
  ) 
 -- in (1,3,5) -- FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0
 -- in (1,5) --  'NA' and Not 'NON_NA'
 -- in (1,2,3,5,6) --  ('NA' or 'NON_NA') 
  in (1,2,3) --  ('NA' or 'NON_NA') and Not 'PSG_REQUIRED'
order by id
;
```

Execute plan

```
EXPLAIN
-> Filter: ((((case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NA',status_column) > 0) then 1 else 0 end) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NON_NA',status_column) > 0) then 2 else 0 end)) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'PSG_REQUIRED',status_column) > 0) then 4 else 0 end)) in (1,3,5))  (cost=2.11 rows=3) (actual time=0.0219..0.0395 rows=3 loops=1)
    -> Index range scan on test using ix_keys over ((((case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NA',`status_column`) > 0) then 1 else 0 end) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NON_NA',`status_column`) > 0) then 2 else 0 end)) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'PSG_REQUIRED',`status_column`) > 0) then 4 else 0 end)) = 1) OR ((((case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NA',`status_column`) > 0) then 1 else 0 end) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NON_NA',`status_column`) > 0) then 2 else 0 end)) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'PSG_REQUIRED',`status_column`) > 0) then 4 else 0 end)) = 3) OR ((((case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NA',`status_column`) > 0) then 1 else 0 end) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'NON_NA',`status_column`) > 0) then 2 else 0 end)) + (case when (find_in_set(_utf8mb4'PSG_REQUIRED',`status_column`) > 0) then 4 else 0 end)) = 5)  (cost=2.11 rows=3) (actual time=0.0174..0.0343 rows=3 loops=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows where status_column contains 'NA' but not 'NON_NA':

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0 
AND FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) = 0
AND status_column IS NOT NULL
AND status_column != '';
```

Rows where status_column contains 'NON_NA':

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) > 0
AND status_column IS NOT NULL
AND status_column != '';
```

Rows where status_column contains both 'NA' and 'NON_NA':

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NA', status_column) > 0 
AND FIND_IN_SET('NON_NA', status_column) > 0
AND status_column IS NOT NULL
AND status_column != '';
```